# printing dynamic lists items in c#

Tags: list, c#-4.0

I have such a code like below

Main problem is I want to Print on console each list items

```
List<Branches> branchesList = new List<Branches>()
            {
                new Branches(){branchId = 1, branchName="Cardeology"},
                new Branches(){branchId = 2, branchName="Urology"},
                new Branches(){branchId = 3, branchName="Dentistry"},

            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```
foreach(var item in branchesList){
  Console.WriteLine("Branch: " + item.branchId + ", BranchName: "+ item.branchName);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

another way.

```
for(int i = 0; i < branchesList.Count(); i ++){
Console.WriteLine("Branch: " + branchesList[i].branchId + ", BranchName: "+ branchesList[i].branchName);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```